# How to enable a "textView" scrollbar scroll with a thumb?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-scrollview, android-scrollbar

I have a textview that is wrapped around a ScrollView to display a large dump of text. So far, i've played around with enabling the scrollbar with *android:scrollbars="vertical*, and turning it permanently visible with *android:fadeScrollbars="false"*.

The textview scrollbar is so far non-functional. I would like to make it operational. *android:fastScrollEnabled* seems to only work for ListViews, but not for textviews.

Is there a way to achieve simple thumb scrolling function on a textview? Something similar to this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out TextView is not an ideal way. I eventually implemented a ListView to make it work as described above.